# Vim - Get a list of all mappings set in a specific file

Tags: vim

I was looking at my vimrc recently, and I was wondering which mappings I really use.  So, I thought that a *"mapcop"* type plugin would be very useful,
but that would require getting a list of all mappings defined in a certain file.  I know that you can get where a mapping was defined by doing `:verbose {map_type}map {mapping}`, but that won't really cut it for what I want to use it for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

these commands could show `{map_type}map {mapping}` created in certain file:

```
:redir @x
:verbose map
:redir END
:%d|pu x
:g/filename$/-1 y M
:%d|pu m
```

- the `filename` you have to do escaping, like `\~\/[.]vimrc$` for `~/.vimrc`
- after executing this sequence, the mappings created in `filename` will be put in current buffer (the original text in buffer will be cleared)
- you can wrap those commands in function to make it easy to be called.
- note that the mappings in certain file are just last time defined in that file, same as your `verbose map` output

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  Is it possible to make it so I don't have to escape the special characters by putting a `\V` in front of it? _(very nomagic)_

Answer (score 0):

The [tagbar](https://github.com/majutsushi/tagbar) plugin allows you to view all mappings defined in a vimscript file, including your `.vimrc`.